# How can I prevent the displaying of repeating data from Database each time when I add a record all the previous record displayed also

Tags: c#

> Here is the code of display() function of my code! having issue in this code I just want that when I add a new entry then just new entry display with the old data not repeat all the data in database.

```
 void display()
            {
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(str);
                        if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            sqlcon.Open();
                        }
                        String query = "select * from doctor";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
                        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(sdr[0].ToString(), sdr[1].ToString(), sdr[2].ToString(),sdr[3].ToString());
                           
                        }
                        sdr.Close();
                        sqlcon.Close();
                        
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error"+ex);
                    }
            }
            }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWxhB.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to clear your datagridview's data before the add row line.

dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();